# Radio buttom que ao ser selecionado muda o background de uma div e salva no BD o resultado

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Olá, oq quero fazer especificamente são radio buttons que quando um é ativado a cor de fundo da div saia da cor padrão (branco) e mude sua cor de background de acordo com o radio buttom, e salve essa alteração no banco de dados referente a tal cor, sem precisar enviar nenhum tipo de formulário por um botão de enviar.
Ficou meio confuso, então, segue abaixo um exemplo:

Tenho as opções de radio buttom:
opc1, opc2, opc3

Quando ativo a opc1 a div que contem o conjunto de radio buttons fica com seu background totalmente verde, e isso é salvo no BD de forma que sempre que eu voltar ela fique verde e com a sua devida opção de radio selecionada (opc1) e não perca a alteração quando a pagina for atualizada.
Mas se nessa mesma div eu resolvo clicar na opc2, a div troca a cor e passa a ficar laranja, indicando outra coisa, assim salvando isso no BD tbm da mesma maneira, e sobrescrevendo no BD a row que estava armazenada a cor verde, e por fim, se o usuário clicar na opc3, a div passará a ficar vermelha, e também a alteração será salva no BD de forma que sobrescreva a anterior.

Sou novato e em processo de aprendizado no JavaScript, então ainda tenho certa dificuldade nisso apesar de parecer simples, já procurei bastante por isso e não achei nada muito esclarecedor, espero que alguém aqui possa me ajudar, segue abaixo os dois scripts que fiz (são dois porque tentei de duas maneiras, porém ambas falharam, mas vou deixar as duas pra saber qual maneira esta mais correta)

Primeira maneira:

```
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="green" onClick="changeColor('g')"> Verde <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="orange" onClick="changeColor('o')"> Laranja <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="red" onClick="changeColor('r')"> Vermelho <br></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Script maneira 1:

```
function changeColor(color){
        var color = document.div.style.backgroundColor;
        switch(value){
            case 'g':
                color = "#6F8456";
            break;
            case 'o':
                color = "#FA7921";
            break;
            case 'r':
                color = "#670000";
            break;
        }
        document.div.backgroundColor = color;
    }
```

Segunda maneira:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="green" onClick="changeColour('g')"> Verde <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="orange" onClick="changeColour('o')"> Laranja <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="red" onClick="changeColour('r')"> Vermelho <br></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Script Segunda maneira:

```
function changeColour(){
        if("g")
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#6F8456";
        else
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
        if("o")
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#FA7921";
        else
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
        if("r")
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#670000";
        else
            document.div.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
    }
```

Se possível manda o código comentando pra mim tentar entender quais alterações remeteram ao o que, e também fazer o código em JavaScript e NÃO em Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de fazer várias comparações na função, você pode usar *dataset* para pegar os valores das cores:

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" name="green" data-cor="6F8456" onclick="changeColor(this)">
```

O *dataset* acima é o `data-cor="6F8456"`. Por ser padrão, ocultei o `#` do código hexa da cor, que depois você pode incluir no PHP.

Vamos ao código:

Além do *dataset* explicado acima, sugiro no `onclick` enviar um `this` na função. O `this` representa o próprio elemento clicado, e isso facilitará bastante lá na função.

**O HTML ficaria assim:**

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="green" data-cor="6F8456" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Verde <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="orange" data-cor="FA7921" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Laranja <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="red" data-cor="670000" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Vermelho <br></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

**E o JS:**

```
function changeColor(e){
   var cor = e.dataset.cor; //  seleciona a cor pelo dataset
   document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundColor = "#"+cor;

   // envia Ajax
   var http = false;
   if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){ // IE antigos
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }else{
      http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }

   url_ = "pagina.php?cor="+cor; // página onde será gravado no BD
   http.open("GET", url_, true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4) {
         alert(http.responseText); // resposta do Ajax. Se naõ quiser resposta, pode apagar esta linha
      }
   }
   http.send(null);
}
```

O Ajax acima irá enviar para a `pagina.php` o código da cor (sem o `#`). Na página PHP, você deve capturar esse código com `$_GET['cor'];` e gravar no banco.

**Exemplo** funcionando apenas a mudança de cor, já que o snippet aqui não vai enviar nada por Ajax:

```js
function changeColor(e){
   var cor = e.dataset.cor; //  seleciona a cor pelo dataset
   document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundColor = "#"+cor;

   // envia Ajax
   var http = false;
   if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){ // IE antigos
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }else{
      http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }

   url_ = "pagina.php?cor="+cor; // página onde será gravado no BD
   http.open("GET", url_, true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4) {
         //alert(http.responseText); // resposta do Ajax. Se naõ quiser resposta, pode apagar esta linha
      }
   }
   http.send(null);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="green" data-cor="6F8456" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Verde <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="orange" data-cor="FA7921" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Laranja <br></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colors" name="red" data-cor="670000" onclick="changeColor(this)"> Vermelho <br></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Não funcionou corretamente, ao ser enviado para o BD ele não sabe diferenciar as 3 cores uma das outras, independente da opção radio que eu marque ele salva "cor" no BD, e ao atualizar a página, a cor selecionada volta à padrão (branca)

Comment: @LuizOleia Tem que colocar o `#` antes do código da cor no PHP

Comment: Eu coloquei e não funcionou, a diferença é que agora o campo no BD fica em branco, coloque o código assim: $status = $_GET['#cor'];

Comment: Não é isso não.. o GET estava certo... vc tem que colocar o `#` no PHP onde vc quer colocar a cor no elemento, algo assim: `<div style="background: #<?=cor ?>">`

Comment: O código da cor possui um `#` antes dos números, certo? Como vc está salvando no banco apenas os números, é preciso concatenar no código o número salvo no banco com o `#`, ficando assim: `#6F8456`

Comment: Ah sim, não tinha entendido isso do php, mas mesmo assim ainda não funcionou e ainda envia apena a palavra "cor" pro BD, na ultima hora tentei de varias maneiras e até agora nenhuma delas funcionaram

Comment: Olha como esta o código:
<div id="radioCor" style="background: #<?php= $status ?>">

A variável $status é como eu referenciei o valor da cor no meu código de envio do php que eu já tinha pronto

Comment: Acho que a sintaxe está errada. Teria que ser assim: `<div id="radioCor" style="background: #<?=$status ?>">`... mas olha no código-fonte da página e veja o que está retornando do PHP...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function verde() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
}

function laranja() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFA500"
}

function vermelho() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>xxxx</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="cor" value="v" onClick="verde()" /> Verde
      <br />

      <input type="radio" name="cor" value="l" onClick="laranja()" /> Laranja
      <br />

      <input type="radio" name="cor" value="r" onClick="vermelho()" /> Vermelho
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```